# Pass Variable to another page using Worker.js - WinJs

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1, winrt-async

I am working on a project that contain an Iframe on my default.html page,
I am trying to pass a variable from 1st page to my iframe using Workers.js as a mediator,

Mean to say that :

```
My First page : default.html, that send message to worker.js 
-----------------------------
|    default.html           |      var worker = Worker("ms-appx:///js/worker.js");
|                           |      worker.postMessage({ calc: 1000 });
|              --------     | 
|             |internal|    | 
|             | iframe |    |
|             |        |    |
|              --------     |
-----------------------------
```

Worker.js:-->

```
var total;
onmessage = function (event) {
calc = event.data.calc;
for (var i = 0; i <= calc; i++) {
    //some work
   total = 1+i;   //as example
};

postMessage({ calc: total });}
```

Now That i try to receive message to Iframe that uses same worker.js

iframe local page :

```
 var worker = Worker("ms-appx:///js/worker.js");
 worker.addEventListener("message",function (e) {
  alert(e.data.calc); //not getting message from worker.js on this page ???
          });
```

Is their any solution to pass message from one page to another using worker.js ??

Sorry for any grammar mistakes !!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this with a Worker alone - you would need a [`SharedWorker`](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-shared-web-workers-html5/), but they are [not yet supported in Internet Explorer](http://caniuse.com/sharedworkers) (which is what Windows Native apps run). You could set something up with passing messages between the iframe and it's parent, but not with the Worker API directly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: **No there isn't**

> Workers run in a "sandbox" and have limited scope. They cannot access
>   most of the object model of the webpage but do have access to the
>   global core JavaScript objects.

A worker cannot be shared between two pages. As jackerella says you may use a shared worker, but they are not supported yet.

Have a look at the last line of the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453265.aspx), it says:

> Shared workers are not supported in this release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. i used a local storage in worker and post it to my iframe page...and local storage variable changes by the 1st page..so here i can do trick to share :) @Maurizio In denmark

Comment: good. but consider that you may be able to use the local storage also without the worker. :)

Comment: ya you right, but i not want to put,setInterval like function on my main page or iframe,Its better to use setInterval on worker,so i use it on worker and pass message to my iframe with the interval of 25ms..so my page not hangs and UI also works great ..@Maurizio In denmark